# HTTP Requst in the POST Method from one service to another service+SpringBoot REST API

Tags: spring, spring-boot, httprequest, microservices

I used SpringBoot REST API Microservices.
I have three Microservices such as player and game and score.
In the POST Method of score Microservice, I want to send HTTP request to the Player Microservice to get the player object by its nickname.
I read something about RestTemplate, but when I use this:

```
final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/player";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    Player player = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, Player.class);
```

I have an error, because my services are in different directories and inside score service, it does not know Player Class.
I do not know how can I do HTTP request from one Rest service to another one.
the Score Controller in the score service:

```
   @RestController
@RequestMapping("/score")
public class ScoreController {
    @Autowired
    private ScoreRepository repo;
    
    //POST Score
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> createScore(@RequestBody @JsonView(Views.class) @Valid  Score score) {
        final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/player";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        Player player =restTemplate.getForObject(uri, Player.class);
        
        
        return null;}

}
```

Comment: What error it is throwing? The services are called using restTemplates only. Just verify if the other server is up and running i.e., if your are really able to hit "http://localhost:8080/player" from Postman, etc. Also Is your other API expecting a GET call?

Comment: In responseType you've to provide a class whose object you are expecting as response from the called API.

Comment: @SanketSingh sorry I deleted, because I used again in the firs form and I saw I have error for creating Player Class in my service. but I have Player class but in another service

Comment: If the error is still coming you can add the helpful code so that I can get idea what is going on or atleast the error.

Comment: @SanketSingh ok I did it. Player player =restTemplate.getForObject(uri, Player.class); but it asked me to define Player Class in this service

Comment: @SanketSingh you mean I put my code here?!

Comment: That you've to create id you are expecting a response of particular type. You should have that type created first in your tree.

Comment: @SanketSingh could you send me a link that help me to understand better, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are are trying to call an API of Player microservice from Score microservice, you can create a new Player class in the Score microservice which should have the same instance variables as the Player class in Player microservice.

For inter-microservice communication, you can create copies of the same DTO classes in both microservices- one for request and the other for response.

Other options are to create a shared-library for both the microservices and share the DTO class or make use of client libraries.

Comment: the first one, I am not interested in. could you share with me any link for the second suggestion, please

Comment: Please refer this [link](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2016/06/13/code-reuse-in-microservices-architecture.html).